# How to call a method defined in a class extension from parent class swift

Tags: swift, class, extension-methods

Is it good practice / possible in Swift to call a class extension method, from parent class? I get compile error saying ParentClass has no member. It can't see the function in the extension?

```
class ParentClass: NSObject {   

   public func doingManyThings() {
      doSomething() // Error: Value of type ParentClass has no member 'doSomething'
   }
}
```

in a different swift file

```
extension ParentClass {
   func doSomething {
     print("this will do something")
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course it is possible... Regarding being a "good practice", I think it's open to interpretation. BTW use of `ParentClass` is kind of ambiguous in your question since there is no inheritance involved in your example.

Comment: What are the colons for? What is the question? Is it why your code doesn’t compile? It’s the colons. Otherwise there’s no problem.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Target membership of swift file containing the extension was missing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class A {
    func aMethod() {
        extensionMethod()
    }
}

class B: A {
    func bMethod() {
        extensionMethod()
    }
}

extension A {
    func extensionMethod() {
        print("totally possible")
    }
}
```

class B will inherit class A methods, even through extensions, 
but class A will not recieve class B extension methods.

Comment: This answer is not very useful without an explanation of the code and how it answers the question

Comment: thanks Itamar - i get a compile error - see edits above

Comment: your doSomething method inside the extension is missing '()'.
no need for that NSObject inheritance.